Type error when passing the union of two functions as a generic parameter
The Typescript code below creates a function func with the union type (() => number) | (() => boolean). If I call func directly I get a number | boolean result as expected. However, when I try to pass func to call (a generic function that calls its argument) I get a type error. Why does type checking fail in this second case?
function a() {
  return 0;
}

function b() {
  return false;
}

const func = Math.random() > 0.5 ? a : b;

const resultA = func(); // ok, number | boolean

function call<R>(func: () => R): R {
  return func();
}

const resultB = call(func); // error

Running deno check code.ts give the following error:
error: TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type '(() => number) | (() => boolean)' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => number'.
  Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type '() => number'.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
const resultB = call(func); // error

If I redefine call as shown below then the code works, but I'm curious why the first version doesn't work.
function call<F extends (() => any)>(func: F): ReturnType<F> {
  return func();
}

